# Use FFMPEG to create xvid avi from image sequence

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm having trouble encoding a sequence of images (that might not start from 0000) to an avi

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -framerate 30 -start_number 560 -i "images_%04d.png" -an -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 video.avi
```

Works, but is an uncompressed .avi (and is therefore enormous in size). So we try to encode it with xvi:

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -framerate 30 -start_number 560 -i "images_%04d.png" -vcodec xvid video.avi -an video.avi
```

Only that doesn't do the trick, it says unknown encoder 'xvid'. I can convert the images to an xvid .avi in VirtualDub - I just want to learn how to do in via a command line in FFMPEG

Comment: xvid output `video.avi` playing in VLC player ? or, Are you able to play it in any media player? try installing the `libxvid` codec on your system, that might help.

Comment: Oops that should of read -vcodec xvid video.avi. As it does now

Comment: I asked whether the avi file can be played by any media player or not

Comment: WMP & Virtual dub won't play it. VLC will play it back, but the video is poor (artifacts & streaking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use codec names recognised by ffmpeg. For MPEG-4 part 2 it is either "mpeg4", a native FFmpeg encoder, or the external encoding library "libxvid". So your command should include `-vcodec mpeg4` or `-vcodec libxvid`.

A complete list of codecs supported by ffmpeg is generated by `ffmpeg -codecs`. You can also run `ffmpeg -encoders` or `ffmpeg -decoders` if you want to be more specific. To list private options (these are specific to each encoder) use `ffmpeg -h encoder=mpeg4`.